# Fill textbox from dropdownlist selection in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fill a textbox from jquery after selecting an option from the dropdownlist.  I include some snippets of the code.

This is the markup of the view.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DependantID, "DependantID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DependantID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "GetRegNo()" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DependantID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            <span id="loading_progress1" style="display: none;">Please wait...</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegNo, new { @Value = @ViewBag.Regno, @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegNo, new { @Value = Regno, @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the jquery code i am hoping to achieve

```
function GetRegNo() {
    var dependid = $('#DependantID').val();
    var dprogress = $('#loading_progress1');
    dprogress.show();
    //alert(schoolid);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        //url: '@Url.Action("/Patients/FillClass")',
        url: '/Patients/FillClass',
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { DependID: dependid },
        success: function (stud) {
            $("#RegNo").html("");  ///clear entry before appending
            $("#RegNo").html() = stud.regno;
            alert("I reach here");
            alert("data.regno " + stud.regno);
        //$.each(studi, function (i, stude) {
        //$("#SClassID").append(
        //$('<option></option>').val(stude.SClassID).html(stude.Class));
       // });
        dprogress.hide();
        },
        error: function (response) {
        alert("Error: " + response.responseText);
        dprogress.hide();
        }

     });
```

Then this is from the controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult FillClass(int? dependid)
    {
        if (dependid == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        string regno="";
        var N = db.Patients.Max(f => (int?)f.PatientID).GetValueOrDefault(0);
        N++;
        string Nt = Convert.ToString(N);
        if (dependid == 1)
        {

           regno = "M" + Convert.ToString((DateTime.Now).ToString("yy")) + BizLogic.Right("00000" + Nt, 5);
        }
        else
        {

            regno = "D" + Convert.ToString((DateTime.Now).ToString("yy")) + BizLogic.Right("00000" + Nt, 5);
        }
        return Json(regno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

So from my code snippets above, when there is a change in the dropdownlist, the java is called which in turn call the method in the controller and fills the textbox. If there is a better way, I am all open.  Thank you.

Comment: You posted a bunch of code. Is it not working? You don't have a clear problem state in your question. Also, you should never refer to "JavaScript" as "Java" as they're completely different.

Comment: Thanks for the correction about the Java and Javascript thing, my bad. But I post the codes so that what i am trying to achieve may be seen.

Comment: And no it is not working!

Comment: Again, you have not provided a clear problem statement in your question. I don't know what "not working" means. You need to be specific in describing exactly what is not working.

Comment: I want to perform a sort of cascading dropdownlist, but instead of filling another dropdown, it will like to fill a textbox.  Hope that explains what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with the jquery script. I will post the change and point to the change. It had to do with my assignment. the line I marked here is posted the value into the textbox.

```
function GetRegNo() {
    var dependid = $('#DependantID').val();
    var dprogress = $('#loading_progress1');
    dprogress.show();
    //alert(schoolid);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        //url: '@Url.Action("/Patients/FillClass")',
        url: '/Patients/FillClass',
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { DependID: dependid },
        success: function (stud) {
            $("#RegNo").html("");  ///clear entry before appending
     here:  $('input#RegNo').val(stud); //i missed it here, changing to this changed solved the problem, compare with with script in the question

        dprogress.hide();
        },
        error: function (response) {
        alert("Error: " + response.responseText);
        dprogress.hide();
        }

     });
   }
```